# Spring Boot bootRun on Java 6

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm having trouble with the autoconfigurer for Jetty on Spring Boot 1.5.8. I need to use Jetty 8 instead of Jetty 9 for Java 6 compatibility, but the autoconfigurer does not detect the jetty classes:

```
   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext' (OnClassCondition)
```

The dependencies part of my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.12'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web', {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
    }

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.7.9' // last version for Java 6
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.7.9'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.7.9.1'

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    //providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty', {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket'
    }
    def JETTY8_VERSION = '8.1.22.v20160922'
    ['jetty-server', 'jetty-webapp', 'jetty-servlets', 'jetty-continuation', 'jetty-client',
            'jetty-http', 'jetty-util', 'jetty-io', 'jetty-servlet', 'jetty-xml', 'jetty-security'].each {
        providedRuntime "org.eclipse.jetty:$it:$JETTY8_VERSION"
    }
}
```

This subsequently results in:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    ...
```

The strange part is, if I declare `EmbeddedServletContainerFactoryBean` explicitly, it works:

```
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    try {
        def clazz = Class.forName('org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory')
        clazz.newInstance()
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError cnfe) {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: Which spring boot version. Also why the complex addition of jetty? Just set the proper version. Set `ext['jetty.version'] = '8.1.22.v20160922'`  instead what you have now. The same applies to Jackson `ext['jackson.version`] = '2.7.9'`.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's 1.5.8. And I did it that way because I didn't know any better.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5 requires by default Java 7, you need to do additional configuration for Java 6 which is quite nicely explained in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6).

Comment: @M.Deinum Changing the dependency section to using `ext` from what I had before was enough for the autoconfigurer to work (though I'm not sure exactly why). If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spring Boot 1.5 [requires](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements) Java 7 or higher to run. However it is possible to run Spring Boot 1.5 on Java 6 and that is quite nicely documented in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6).

In your case you are overthink things it is as simply as specifying the desired Jetty version.

```
ext['jetty.version'] = '8.1.22.v20160922'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.12'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web', {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
    }

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.7.9' // last version for Java 6
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.7.9'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.7.9.1'

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty', {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket'
    }
}
```

This way Spring Boot will include the proper versions and you don't need to include them yourself.

Comment: What the link to Reference Guide for this? Seems it's old now

Comment: Linked to Spring Boot 1.5 documentation instead of the current (Spring Boot 1.5 is the last to support java 6, Spring boot 2 requires Java 8).